# setting blob url to object using javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, blob, internet-explorer-11

I have a webservice which returns PDF blob. This PDF needs to be rendered in the form once user clicks a button.

I have invoked this service using AJAX call and got the response back as blob.
I have the following html object, which renders the pdf.

```
<object id="PdfObject" width="100%" height="100%" type="application/pdf"  data=""></object>
```

Post webservice invocation, I have set the blob to the above object using the following jQuery statement.

```
var sBlobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(oPdf_Blob);
$("#PdfObject").attr('data', sBlobUrl);
```

With the above code, I am able to show the PDF file in the webpage. It works in all browser except IE 11 :(

In IE 11, it throws error: Access Denied.

```
document.getElementById("PdfObject").data = sBlobUrl;
```

Can someone please guide me on how to set blob url to data attribute of  using JavaScript/jQuery, which works for all browsers including IE?

Note: I don't want to save download and save the pdf. I just want to display the pdf in browser.

Regards,

SAP Learner

Comment: have you tried readAsBinaryString or readAsArrayBuffer?

Comment: So I tried from a VM, and indeed it throws when `data` is set to a blobURI... You could try an `<iframe>`, but anyway, IE11 doesn't seem to have a pdf viewer built-in.

Comment: iframe is an alternative. However, I face issues with iframe when used in mobile devices, hence thought of sticking with <object> which works well everywhere (but not IE). Any other thoughts on this..?

Comment: Can someone please provide a solution here...

Comment: Can someone please help me here....